# How to have maven resolve a dependency of a dependency which was created by a non-default profile for some classifier?

Tags: java, maven

Given a library which has different dependencies depending on a profile, say for example

```
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>cuda-10.1</envClassifier>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcuda</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cuda-10.0</id>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>cuda-10.0</envClassifier>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcuda</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

I am creating artefacts with different classifiers, say for example

```
library-1.0.0-cuda-10.0
```

and

```
library-1.0.0-cuda-10.1
```

(here `cuda-10.0` and `cuda-10.1` are the classifiers for the artefact `library-1.0.0`).

If another project references this library, say for example as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.finmath</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>cuda-10.0</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

then the correct artefact is pulled (here library-1.0.0-cuda-10.0.jar) but the dependency tree (via `mvn dependency:tree`) shows the wrong *dependencies of the dependency*. In this example it shows jcuda-10.1.0 and not juda-10.0.0.

This issue is due to an artefact having a single pom.xml for all classifiers (and the default profile kicks in).

**Question 1:** Can you have dedicated pom.xml in the repositories for different classifiers, to reflect the correct dependencies?

Apparently the issue cannot be resolved by setting a profile (`-P` parameter) on the outer project, because profile selectors are not passed to the `pom`s of the dependencies. It looks as if profiles do not walk down the dependency tree.

**Question 2:** Is there a way to pass a profile selector to a pom of a dependency to select the right *dependencies of the dependency*?

I found two options to resolve the problem, but I am not very happy with them.

1. The first one would be to not have a default profile with a dependency in the pom of the library. In that case the user of the library (here library-1.0.0) has to specify the correct classifier and the correct downstream dependencies. This appears to be cumbersome. Also note that in this case the build of the library would fail without specification of the profile.
2. It is possible to use the profile to alter the name (or version) of the artefact. Since each version or artefact comes with its own pom, this allows to specify profile specific dependencies to be resolved.

However, I believe there should be a better solution, because otherwise it looks as if the specification of dependencies in profiles makes no sense for artefacts which are libraries, that is, which are themselves dependencies of another projects.

**Question 3:** What is the Maven way to resolve this issue?

PS: The question arose in this project: http://finmath.net/finmath-lib-cuda-extensions/

Comment: Not an answer, but here is how [fb-contrib](https://github.com/mebigfatguy/fb-contrib) has solved a similar issue. They have two main branches, 'findbugs' and 'spotbugs'. Code is committed to findbugs, and then merged to spotbugs. This results in two separate artefacts: `v7.4.7` and `v7.4.7.sb`.

Comment: Thank you Boris. This is essentially the option two "create two different artefacts". Given that the Dependency is selecting the Cuda version and there could be some different version, I was hoping for a solution with a smaller footprint.

Comment: I agree. But you have 2 different JARs with two different set of classes. According to this [article](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/), if you are creating two different JARs, you should split the project up into two interdependent modules.

Comment: I see. While I found some references that classifiers are used for things like `sources` or `javadoc`, I also saw examples to use classifiers to distinguish libraries build against different JDKs. Your comment suggests that his is bad practice.  However, in my case it may be that the Java classes are actually really the same and its just the linkage to some native libraries that differs...   - maybe this is a corner case.

Answer (score 1):

I found a lightweight solution for the problem.

1. You may activate a profile though a property.
2. Properties may not be passed from a `pom` to the `pom`s of it's dependencies, but a property which is set on the command line acts on both `pom`s.
3. Hence, instead of using a profile on the command line, use a property and activate the corresponding profiles in your project's pom and the library's pom.

So in the above example, the (outer) project (which references the library) has a profile

```
    <profile>
        <id>cudaversion</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>cuda.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <finmath-cuda.classifier>cuda-${cuda.version}</finmath-cuda.classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

which sets the classifier of its dependency, that is this project has a dependency to `library-1.0.0`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.finmath</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>${finmath-cuda.classifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

And the pom of library-1.0.0 has a profile which is **activated by the *same* property** as in

```
    <profile>
        <id>cuda-10.0</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>cuda.version</name>
                <value>10.0</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>cuda-10.0</envClassifier>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcuda</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

The outer project is then build with `mvn -Dcuda.version=10.0` to activate both profiles.

Comment: yes, use profile -> activation-> property , and use mvn -D{property}=xxx , with maven-jar-plugin config  'classifier',  maven support use activation - property to active  all pom profile